# Error: command 'gpg' failed with exit status 2 when create a dist of Sphinx python package

Tags: python, python-sphinx, setuptools, gnupg

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and Python 2.7.3, I want to use a setup option for [Sphinx 1.2b3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Sphinx/1.2b3) python package, to create a distribution package and upload it to a pypi server by using this command:

```
python setup.py register -r <MY_PYPI_SERVER> sdist upload -r <MY_PYPI_SERVER>
```

I used that command with others python packages and it worked fine, but with sphinx got the following error (also some of the command out is added to help):

```
hard linking utils/check_sources.py -> Sphinx-1.2b3/utils
hard linking utils/convert.py -> Sphinx-1.2b3/utils
hard linking utils/pylintrc -> Sphinx-1.2b3/utils
hard linking utils/reindent.py -> Sphinx-1.2b3/utils
copying setup.cfg -> Sphinx-1.2b3
Writing Sphinx-1.2b3/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'Sphinx-1.2b3' (and everything under it)
running upload
gpg --detach-sign --local-user 36580288 -a dist/Sphinx-1.2b3.tar.gz
gpg: skipped "36580288": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
error: command 'gpg' failed with exit status 2
```

After that the package is not uploaded to the pypi server, so any help to solve it? I need to install something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to sign with a GPG key that does not belong to you (and for which you do not possess the private key).  The key in your example, 0x36580288, belongs to Georg Brandl.  You need to sign your package with your own key or with a key you created for signing software distributions.